# Unable to validate token on server side using express-jwt with MEAN stack

Tags: angular, jwt, mean-stack, express-jwt

I am trying to secure my apis using express-jwt. I am using the MEAN (Angular 4) stack. I've tried many variations of the code below and cannot figure out why I cannot validate a token.

The code listed below returns a `401 Unauthorized to the client`. Other variations return `UnauthorizedError: Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]`. Does anyone see anything wrong with the code below?

**Server Side Code**

In my app.ts file I have the following:

```
  app.use('/api/volunteers/', jwt({
    secret: 'test',
    credentialsRequired: false,
    getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
      if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        // console.log(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer')
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
        return req.query.token;
      }
      return null;
    }
  }));
```

Questions:

1. Does this set req.user if the token in the header is valid?
2. Do I need to call getToken() explicitly?

In my routes.ts file I have:

```
 app.get('/api/volunteers',
    function(req, res) {
    console.log('req user ' + req.user);
      // auth
      if (!req.user) {
        return   res.sendStatus(401);
      }
      // logic
      Volunteer.find({}, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err);
          return console.error(err);
        }
        res.json(docs);
      });
    });
```

Note: Adding `jwt({secret: 'test'}),` after the first line in the code directly above returns `UnauthorizedError: Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]`.

User Model:

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
  password: String,
  role: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

export default User;
```

User Handler:

```
import BaseHandler from './base';
import User from '../models/user';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';

export default class UserHandler extends BaseHandler {
  model = User;

  login = (req, res) => {
    this.model.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
      if (!user) { return res.sendStatus(403); }
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (error, isMatch) => {
        if (!isMatch) { return res.sendStatus(403); }
        // why sign with user
        // why do I need test
        const token = jwt.sign({user: user}, 'test');
        res.status(200).json({ token: token });
      });
    });
  };
}
```

**Client Side Code**

A section of my service:

```
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.headers.append('authorization', localStorage.token);
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  }

  getVolunteers(): Observable<Volunteer[]> {
    return this.http.get('/api/volunteers', this.options)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch(handleError);
  }
```

Comment: Does this set req.user if the token in the header is valid?

Ans: You need to set req.user by userself

UnauthorizedError: Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]

This error is because of the following line in app.ts

return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
You must return the whole token including 'Bearer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server side you can do it like this

```
var authentication = require('./auth');
router.route('/create')
    .all(authentication)
    .post(function(req, res){
        // Your Code
    });
```

And In auth.js write following code

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple'),
    common = require('./common'),
    secretKey = require('./key');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    var token = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (token) {
        try {
            var token = jwt.decode(token, secretKey);
            var user = token.user; // Get user from token in your way
            return next();
        } catch (err) {
            // Throw error
        }
    } else {
       // Throw error
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using jwt-simple and following this example instead of express-jwt